# A question about JRM error : Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: handle

Tags: java, jvm, launch, steam

I am trying to deploy a JAVA game on the steam, they copy me an error detail:
$ bin/java -jar game.exe

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: handle
    at java.io.FileDescriptor.initIDs(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileDescriptor.(FileDescriptor.java:137)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1188)
```

Does anyone know what is the issue is and how to solve it?

Thanks!

I don't get the error when I run this command on my local on three machines.

Comment: Combining the `-jar` option with an `.exe` file is highly suspicious. Besides that, what do you expect us to tell you, given this little amount of information? Apparently, your Java installation is broken.

Comment: exe is ok, because it is built by launch4J, I don't have any clue, I stop by this error for  4 weeks. I know it JRE initial error, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: An exe built by launch4J still is an exe file, not a jar file. Why don’t you just run the exe, as it is supposed to be used?

Comment: yeah, we will run game.exe on release version, to use the command line to debug to get the above error log. I tested the command line on my local, the game can be launched normally, however, the steam tester can not launch it with the same command line on their side, thanks.